# numerical solver for stochastic optimal control problems

Tags: constrained-optimization, optimal-control

can any one recommend numerical solver (c/c++ library preferred) for stochastic optimal control problems? For deterministic optimal control I found something like that: http://abs-5.me.washington.edu/ocp/index.html Now looking for something similar for stochastic OCP.

Comment: This was originally [posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185756/numerical-solver-for-stochastic-optimal-control-problems) on mathoverflow (no answers there).

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this?  Say in Python/R prefereable?